# Recursively defined sequence of hyperoperations in Python

Tags: python, function, recursion, currying, integer-arithmetic

I have created a simple function to iterate binary operations, and I would like to use it to recursively define the sequence of integer hyperoperations (succession, addition, multiplication,...).

The iteration function is:

```
# f : (int,int) -> int
# x,y : int

def right_iterate(f,x,y):
    a = x
    while y - 1 > 0:
        y = y - 1
        x = f(a,x)
    return x
```

Ideally, I would like to define the sequence of hyperoperations like this:

```
# H : int -> ( (int, int) -> int )
# n,x,y : int

def H(n)(x,y):
    if n == 0:
        return x+1
    else:
        return right_iterate(H(n-1),x,y)
```

Basically an exact translation of the equation I am working off of, but this is not supported in Python. I think I need to do something analogous to currying and define a function `h(n,x,y)-->H(n)(x,y)`, but I'm not sure how.

I've tried using

```
# H : int -> ( (int,int) -> int )
# h : (int,int) -> int
# n,x,y : int

def H(n):
    def h(x,y):
        if n == 0:
            return y + 1
        else:
            return right_iterate(H(n-1),x,y)
    return h
```

This isn't right, but it seems to be on the right track
When `n` is 1, this evaluates the same as

```
if y != 0:
    return x + y - 1
else:
    return x + y
```

When `n` is 2, this evaluates to `

```
if y != 0:
    return x * y - (y -1)
else:
    return x
```

Comment: What are you asking is not clear do you want to do multiple operations at same time?

Comment: I want to do one operation at a time. I'm trying to define each operation recursively so that H(0)(x,y)=s(x), H(1)(x,y)=x+y, H(2)(x,y)=x*y, and so on.

Comment: @GovindaMalavipathirana H(n) should be a function that takes in two integers and outputs an integer.

Comment: You are trying to implement a switch here, According to `H` functions inputs execution will be different, right?

Comment: @GovindaMalavipathirana Yes, `n` determines which operation is being carried out.

Comment: So you have finite number of operations right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204564/discussion-between-r-burton-and-govinda-malavipathirana).

Answer (score 0):

Based on a quick study of [hyperoperations on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation), I'm guessing you want something like:

```
from operator import add

def right_iterate(f, a, b):
    c = a

    while b > 0:
        a = f(c, a)
        b -= 1

    return a

def H(n, a, b):
    if n == 0:
        return right_iterate(add, 1, b)

    if b == 0:

        if n == 1:
            return a

        if n == 2:
            return 0

        if n >= 3:
            return 1

    return H(n - 1, a, H(n, a, b - 1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(H(0, 2, 3))  # 1 + 3
    print(H(1, 2, 3))  # 2 + 3
    print(H(2, 2, 3))  # 2 * 3
    print(H(3, 2, 3))  # 2 ** 3
    print(H(4, 2, 3))  # 2 ** 2 ** 2
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
4
5
6
8
16
>
```

Comment: This works, but I would like to use `right_iterate` to define addition from succession, multiplication from addition, and so on. For example, `right_iterate(add,a,b)=a*b`.